# Info.plist Localizations Autocomplete

Tags: ios, localization, plist, info.plist

My app is localized in 5 languages: English, German, French, Italian, Spanish.
In the info.plist file I've decided to add the **"Localizations"** or **"CFBundleLocalizations"** key and define the supported languages for the app.

The fields inside "Localizations" array in the info.plist have an autocomplete option which displays: "Chinese", "English", "French", "German", "Italian", "Japanese", "Korean".

My questions are:

1. Is this autocomplete list predefined?
2. If I want to add Spanish to the list of supported localizations, should I write "es" or "Spanish"?

Could not find any reference on the web for this.

**P.S.** The app's localization to Spanish works as expected.

Comment: So what worked, "es" or "Spanish" or either?

Comment: That happened quite a while ago, and I don't have the source code (was working for a company back then) but if I remember correctly we went with 'es' eventually.